# Use the generic type of an extended type what was supplied as generic type

Tags: typescript

Inception time!!

Consider the following set-up:

```js
interface Props {
  [k: string]: any;
}

abstract class Model<P extends Props> {
  // omitted...
}

abstract class Factory<M extends Model<P>, P extends Props> {
  abstract createInstance(props: P): M;
}
```

Now every time I implement a "Factory" I will have to supply the "Props" type explicitly, but the "Model" type already has it:

```js
interface UserProps extends Props {}
class UserModel extends Model<UserProps> {}
class UserFactory extends Factory<UserModel, UserProps> {}
```

Is it possible to use the generic type of an extended type what was supplied as generic type? So in the use case presented above:

**Is it possible to use the type "Props", an extension of the required generic type "P" in "Model", as a generic type in "Factory", a class what requires generic type M to be extended with the "Model" type?**

The implementation for this use case presented above works fine but unfortunately will become more challenging to maintain when the amount of "Factory" implementations grow.

There are several things I tried but none of these where syntactically correct:

1. `P extends Props`, gave the following errors:

   1. Cannot find name 'P'.
   2. '?' expected.

   ```js
   abstract class Factory<M extends Model<P extends Props>> {
     //                                   ^1             ^2
     abstract createInstance(props: P): M;
   }
   ```
2. `Props as P`, gave the following errors:

   1. '>' expected
   2. ',' expected
   3. '{' expected

   ```js
   abstract class Factory<M extends Model<Props as P>> {
     //                                         ^1 ^2^3
     abstract createInstance(props: P): M;
   }
   ```

Am I missing something or is it simply not there (yet)?

Comment: What are you doing with `class UserModel<UserProps> {}` and `class UserFactory<UserModel, UserProps> {}`?  Don't you mean `class UserModel extends Model<UserProps> {}` and `class UserFactory extends Factory<UserModel, UserProps> {}`?  Is that just a typo?

Comment: In order for this to be a [mcve], you should give `Model` enough structure to show a dependence on the generic `P`; if you omit everything, you end up with [weird results](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  Can I assume something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBz6dN) where `Model` has a property of type `P`?

Comment: @jcalz yes, its a typo and yes you can assume something like that. I would even accept that as a correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: a type like `class Model<P extends Props> {}` with no structural dependence on `P` is not good example code.  It has [weird effects](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--); for example, `Model<SomeProps>` and `Model<SomeOtherProps>` will be completely identical to each other, and both will be completely identical to the empty object type `{}`.  In order to avoid such weirdness, in what follows I will add a property so that there is some structural dependence:

```
abstract class Model<P extends Props> {
    abstract props: P; // structural dependence
}
```

---

You can't declare a type parameter `P` where you're trying to do it; as you can see, it's syntactically invalid.  There are only a few places where you can bring new type parameters into existence... if you don't want to write `class Factory<M extends Model<P>, P extends Props> {}`, you will have to do something else.

What you really *want* to do here is to use something like an [*existentially-quantified* generic type parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  Imagine you could say `exists P extends Props` to mean "for *some* `P` that extends `Props`" without having to specify it.  And you'd declare something like `class Factory<M extends Model<P>, exists P extends Props> {}`, and then you could later refer to `Factory<UserModel>` and have `P` inferred.  But there is no direct support for existential types in TypeScript.

Or you could imagine something like *partial* type parameter inference, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), where you could manually specify one of your two type parameters while letting the compiler *infer* the other one.  And you'd declare something like `class Factory<M extends Model<P>, P extends Props = infer> {}` and then you could later refer to `Factory<UserModel>` and have `P` inferred.  But again, there is no direct support for this.

---

Barring the ideal solutions, I think the closest you'll be able to get to what you're looking for is something like this:

```
type PropsType<M> = M extends Model<infer P> ? P : never;

abstract class Factory<M extends Model<any>> {
    abstract createInstance(props: PropsType<M>): M;
}
```

Here, `PropsType<T>` takes a `Model<P>` for some `P`, and returns `P`.  Since we're not going to define `P` inside of `Factory`, you need some way to get `P` from `M`...   hence `PropsType`.

And then your `Factory` only declares `M extends Model<any>`.  We are using [the `any` "type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), which is intentionally unsound so you are allowed to use it in place of a real `Props`-like type, no matter what sort of dependence `Model<P>` has on `P`.

Now the following will work as you want:

```
declare class UserModel extends Model<UserProps> {
    props: UserProps;
}
declare class UserFactory extends Factory<UserModel> {
    createInstance(props: UserProps): UserModel;
}
```

---

The caveat here is that, since `any` is intentionally unsound, you could pass some weird things as `M`:

```
interface BadModel {
    props: undefined; // undefined should not work
}

class Oops extends Factory<BadModel> {
    createInstance(props: never): BadModel {
        return { props: undefined };
    }
}
```

`BadModel` doesn't extend `Model<P>` for any valid `P`, but it does extend `Model<any>`, so it's accepted by `Factory`.  There might be things that you could do to try to prevent such weirdness, but I wouldn't bother unless you are likely to run into it in practice.

The point is: using `any` is a workaround for the lack of existential types, and such edge cases are what makes this a workaround and not a perfect solution.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAsAFDJnIDaA1gFzI5hSgDmAunXCAJ4DcJAviRJwARgyiIwyBABs4OPAFkMAEwgyAPKmQQAHpBAq86bDgB8BEuWSjxk5Fky46qHsgD07+owCuCMD4SMshqWBCG4UgCQsQxYFxhaE44ACoJEBqKFgC8yIo6+uFGearqGqAw0GgWAPxoyHQgEABu0HyxxLaM9rLyeABikhhQXJkFBsXKapqcXGYWRKTkXRL+0lAQcJAAkiAMnEgAFI6mLslpYZlmAJR0iu2CHSSgkLCIKACqONAmuONFxmSBGQjxIal6G2kcgUyC+0Cm6n+hiUpU0cKgv3MliWZBOzlh3wxyQeYIgEJQvRh6MG-mGXCRxRpYDpGnRCJkCys5AQGy2EF2+xARzxODo6MxtwJ8NRJI6L2g8CQyAAQnAVOzsdYRXQfBEYKAICo3J5kLq1Pqmip6AALDA+GRWkAYKQAd2GVGiHUpeAA8qYGQMhiMNKr1ajOTj1psdnswAcIMdko0WtBJaGNYtrNYNgEoCBgdrTXqDVb+O1rI9QcQgA)